# C# lib allowing loading and saving png files and creating images from a source image?

Tags: c#, image-processing

I have to write a little application that needs to load a png image, read a xml file that defines Rects in this image and ouput a bunch of little images from the initially loaded png image.

Could anybody suggest a c# library to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The .NET Framework already provides the basic tools fully capable of achieving this. (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics(v=vs.110).aspx))

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. I did not notice that.